# how to restore a backup created with kbackup

Tags: kali-linux, backup, restore

ok so I made a backup using the program "Kbackup" on my kali linux. it created a .tar archive and for the life of me i cant figure out how to restore it using kbackup because it says it can but even the documentation doesnt explain how. it does say that it automatically restores the files from each part of the directory i backed up to their original locations, (for example, everything under /etc gets restored to /etc and /opt files to /opt, etc. etc.)

this is the link to the documentation : https://kbackup.sourceforge.net/manual/node45.html

and a Screenshot of the page i mentioned [image]

any advice would be appreciated. im not sure if i shoudl just restore the backup with tar or kbackup. would tar put everything where it goes?

update: ok so here are the steps i follow for making a backup using the kbackup program and where im stuck

first i open kbackup and use the GUI on the left hand side is all the files in my directory, i selected the ones i wanted to backup, [image]

then on the right hand side you select the location for the backup to be saved, in this case i used my external usb thumb drive [image]

then you start backup and it will eventually complete.

when it does it leaves me with a .tar folder compressed in the location i saved it.

the output for the cli version of the program doesnt even mention restoring at all. [image]

Comment: How do you take a backup using this tool?

Comment: i use the GUI interface. i just run in the terminal kbackup and its gui opens and i backlup through that.

Comment: Then that's how you restore. If you can show us the process it's probable someone will spot where you start the restore route

Comment: I think it may actually be because i made the backup on my kali before i cleared my hard drive to reinstall windows because i normally dual boot with akli and windows 11.                    windows had me reboot to finish some updates and instead of restarting it cut off and didnt come back on. the boot was no longer accessable or even showed up anymore. tried just reinstalling windows but its not gonna work apparantly. so i backed up my kali using kbackup to an external usb drive and reinstalled windows after wiping everything and using the bootable windows drive and everything went perfectly

Comment: but i cant seem to find how kbackup restores files as it describes in the documentation i linked.

Comment: ok ill update with the exact steps and screenshot along the way or just record my screen. will update in a few